# "How do I ...X ?" - is this an opinion-based question?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Identifying host machine in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74803224/identifying-host-machine-in-python)

This question was marked as opinion-based. I can't see, where this judgement comes from, which is why I am now asking this question here - expressly asking for your opinion on why this is "opinion-based".

It would be immensely helpful - especially for first-time-askers like me, if there was some kind of feedback, why a specific ruling was called. In my fruitless attempts to sway the moderateur's opinion about the (non-)opinion-based nature of my question, I already changed several details about the used language. English is, as you might have already gathered, not my native tongue, so is was very hard work to try to find all small semantic issues, possibly implying that there is any faint hint of an opinion in this question.

Comment: It doesn't look "opinion based" to me, but it is somewhat broad.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, it might indeed be somewhat broad. If I narrowly knew, what library I should ask about, I might not even have asked the question. Do you have any suggestions about how I could achieve a narrower focus?

Comment: I'm guessing the close voters read it as "I have all these options, but which should I pick?" which is opinion based

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine The problem hereby is that several times I read the complaint about missing research. Even the question-posting-form prompts the user to tell about what attempts they made to solve the question. And here I detail every attempt, with the according reasoning, why this did not solve the problem. Do you suggest, I delete the "Options" section in my question?

Comment: @Acasta: no, I do not know how to make it more focused, and in fact that may be the issue, that you may have a problem and a question that is not yet a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: From the question it is not clear to me at all what answers must provide. Should they pick one identity from a fixed set? Should they handle dynamically adding/removing machines? Do they have to handle reinstallations, updates, …? Can they directly access the host or are containers possible? Must they handle different OS? Personally I would say the question is too broad, but trying to answer surely would draw a wide range of opinions what the identity of a host even is.

Comment: I would place a file in the user's home directory, and use the contents of that file to know which "machine" I'm on.  That's probably not the best solution, and certainly not the only solution.  I could come up with other answers as well.  The right answer?  That depends on your exact use case, and is an opinion as to what's best based on various tradeoffs.  In other words, this is open ended and the definition of opinion based.

Comment: Thank you, @AnonCoward and @MisterMiyagi! I tried to take up all your hints and updated the question. Especially the "Backstory" and "Example" sections seemed to cause some confusion.

Comment: The opinion-based thing is what "identify" means. This is a [known problem in philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus). As you note yourself: "What if you add a PCIe card? If you change the CPU?" Well, what if you replace each part of the computer, one at a time? Although I would instead say this is **unclear**; the onus is on **you** to decide the meaning of "identify" for your own purposes.

Answer (score 12):

The question could be considered to be "opinion based" because there is no clear way for external observer to identify "the right answer". The question already lists several options to achieve what OP think they need and there is no indication what type of solution would be acceptable. At this point the question gives vibe of "give me an answer I will like" rather than some concrete set of requirements.

Note that

- the question probably should stay closed there are plenty similar question for "fingerprinting machine" (including "browser fingerprinting"). All of the approaches have drawbacks and it's up to the questioner to pick one that sucks the least for their case.
- alternatively the question need to strictly define criteria for an answer so it no longer feels unclear/too broad/opinion based.
- the original problem (even if not on-topic on SO) should likely be solved differently by providing that information externally to the script instead of guessing. That makes SO's part of the question less practical and potentially call for more close reasons.

Comment: Thank you, Alexei Levenkov, your observation of missing more definitive criteria was also put forth by another comment under my original question. I adjusted the question accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think "opinion based" is the most appropriate close reason. Your question does have some problems that make it less likely to generate good answers, which I'll try to explain.

A good question should make it very clear what an ideal answer should provide. Explaining what you've tried is helpful insofar as it can provide a bit more context and clarity to your issue. However, spending so many words elaborating on options that don't work is more distracting than it is helpful.

Here's an example of a better way to structure this kind of question, which remains brief and focused, while making it very clear what is expected from an answer.

> I want to do X.
>
> I tried options A, B and C, but they don't work for me because they don't satisfy this condition or that condition.
>
> How can I write some code that does X, while satisfying this condition and that condition?

Then, a good answer would look like:

> Here is some code that does X.
>
> Here is an example of how to use it.
>
> It satisfies this condition because of this reason, and that condition because of that reason.

Comment: Thank you, Hymns For Disco, I did incorporate your advice and strongly shortened the question, thereby not wasting as many words.